# Why won't my first if statement execute if the statement is true? Python

Tags: python

I print my computer number so I can enter it into the player guess to make sure the value is true but when I enter it, it says the number is wrong. I am not sure why that is. Here is my code:

````
def start():

    computerNum = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(computerNum)
    playerGuess = input("Enter your guess: ")

    if playerGuess == computerNum:

        print("You got it! The number was " + str(computerNum))

    if playerGuess != computerNum:

        print("You are wrong, the number is " + str(computerNum))

startPlay = input("Would you like to play the game? ").lower()

if startPlay == 'yes':
    start()```
````

Comment: You are comparing an integer to a string. Cast one of them to the other.

Comment: Try `playerGuess = int(input("Enter your guess:"))`

Comment: *if playerGuess == str(computerNum)* is safest because it then doesn't matter if user input cannot be converted to *int*

Answer (score -1):

cast computerNum  to string or playerGuess  to integer